# how to print the decimal value in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a double value as 47. I divide it by 60, but when I try to print it it shows 0.0000.
It should display 0.7858

How can I do that? Any help?

Here is my code:

```
int minutes = decimal * 60;
float min = (minutes)/60;
NSLog(@"%.4f",min);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
double decimal = 47.0 / 60.0;     // Just so minutes is 47
double minutes = decimal * 60.0;
double min = minutes / 60.0;
NSLog(@"%.4f",min);
```

In Objective C (as well as C and C++), integer division is applied when both left and right operands are integers, so `minutes / 60 = 0`. If you want a floating point operation, use floating points literals.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  int minutes = 40;
  float min = (minutes * 1.0f)/60.0f;
  NSLog(@"%.4f",min);
```

or

```
  int minutes = 40;
  float min = (float)minutes/60.0f;
  NSLog(@"%.4f",min);
```